# Javascript - how to redirect users from old URL to new one so SSL cert matches

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

We have 2 DNS entries for our corporate site; our old domain still works and our new domain is used in all of our ads, but many users have our old site bookmarked.

We installed an SSL cert for 4 pages that require users to enter personal info. I have a redirect for http to https like so:

```
    <script> if(location.protocol.indexOf("https") === -1) {     location.href = location.href.replace("http", "https"); }</script>
```

and it works perfectly unless someone enters the page from our old domain, then the domain name in the URL doesn't match the cert and users get a nasty warning from their browsers.

I copied the following code which I thought would redirect if they came to this page using the previous domain but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    <script>if (document.referrer == 'olddomain.co.jp' || document.referrer == 'www.olddomain.co.jp') == 1)
           { top.location="https://newdomain.com/english/engform.aspx";
```

}

but it doesn't redirect; it still gives me the warning. Any recommendations?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a Javascript redirect and not an HTTP redirect?

Comment: I think referrer will give you the page you are coming from. Can't you just do window.location.href.indexOf("oldDomain.com") > -1?

Comment: @Mark - when I used an HTML redirect, the page kept loading itself. I couldn't get it to redirect to an https version of itself without multiple reloads.

Comment: @major-mann, I can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Then you just need to check if it's old domain and send them to new domain using same method as you described on your question

```
if (location.href.indexOf("oldsite.domain") > -1) location.href = location.href.replace("oldsite.domain", "newsite.domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get certificates for **both** your old domain and your new domain.   Without a certificate for the old domain, the browser shows a security warning **before** your JavaScript runs.

The typical way to do this is to get a subject alternative name (SAN) certificate that covers both your old domain and your new domain.  Then you can use the same certificate, server configuration, and document root for both domains and redirect from one to the other either using `.htaccess` (preferred) or JavaScript like you have been trying.

Answer (score -1):

```
function RedirectUrl() {
var expression = /https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/
var regex = new RegExp(expression);
var current_url = window.location.href;
var redirect_url = "/news"; /* where news is like news.html same news-inspiration is a news-inspiration.html like www.abc.com/news-inspiration */
if (current_url.indexOf('/news-inspiration') > -1) {
    if (!current_url.match(redirect_url) && current_url.match(regex)) {
        window.location.replace(redirect_url);
    }
}
```

}

after making it function call it during any javascript event.
//calling function----

```
RedirectUrl();
```